# Varriant Array remove formulas in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I recently discovered quite fast way to proceed loops via a variant array

```
    With Sht
        LongY = .Rows.Count
        Dat = .Formula

         For r = 5 To 6 'LongY
          If (Dat(r, 1) = "" Or Dat(r, 4) = "") Then GoTo IgnoRow

          LongX = .Columns.Count
          For s = 26 To 27 'LongX
           If (Dat(2, s) = 0 Or Dat(2, s) = "") Then GoTo IgnoCol 'Or Dat(1, s).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
           Price = Dat(2, s)
           Ammount = Dat(r, 4)
           Base = Dat(r, s)

           Material = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Base * Ammount), 2) 'no .values => text
           'MsgBox (Material)
           'CPrice = Material * Price
           'Cost = Cost + CPrice
IgnoCol:
                 Next

         'Dat(r, 5) = Cost
         'Cost = ""
IgnoRow:
          Next
         Sht.Formula = Dat
    End With

End Sub
```

But I don't know how this works which gives me trouble. I have large area for my inputs (also with formulas) so when I loop over this area all my EXCEL FORMULAS transform to .values and I don't know how to avoid this.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: If you want it to reference the formula instead of the value, just replace `Dat = .Value` with `Dat = .Formula`.

Comment: ... and `Table.Value = Dat` with `Table.Formula = Dat`. While you are at it, declaring and attempting to use a variable named *Long* is ill-advised.

Comment: @TheEngineer Now it Is not deleting formulas, but if I want to use values from that formulas in loop, it use it as a text.

Comment: That code won't compile because Long is a reserved word. Also, nothing is happening inside the loop. Could you post your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With red-herrings removed, your original code does this:

```
With Table          ' Note: Table is a Range
    Dat = .Value    ' Dat is now an array of values, with Table.Rows.Count rows
                    '     and Table.Columns.Count columns.
    .Value = .Dat   ' This copies all the values back into the Table cells, 
                    '     replacing any existing formulas with their values.
End With
```

Extracting all the values from an Excel Range into a VBA array is a technique I haven't seen before, but it is very fast and makes for easy-to-read code, so I'll be using it from now on.

But with this convenience comes a cost. If you transfer all the values from the VBA array back into the Range, you wipe out any formulas.

And if you extract the formulas instead of the values (so you can copy back safely), you don't have access to the values of any formula-based cells. That is why your more recent code fails.

The simplest solution is to extract both values and formulas, but copy back just the formulas.

```
Dim Formulas() As Variant, Values() As Variant
With Sht        ' Sht is a Range object
    Values = .Value
    Formulas = .Formula
    For r = ...
        For s = ...
            price = Values(2, s)
            Ammount = Values(r, 4)
            Base = Values(r, s)
            Material = Round(Base * Ammount + 0.005, 2) ' Round Up
            Cost = ...
        Next
        Formulas(r, 5) = Cost
    Next
    .Formula = Formulas
End With
```

Comment: Another option is to use the `HasFormula` property in the loop to check if the cell has a formula and use the `Evaluate` function to return the value of the function. I think your answer is cleaner than mine would have been though.

Comment: `HasFormula` won't work on the array values, just the original cells. The traditional way to do this kind of thing is to work directly with the cells instead of array copies of the values/formulas. In that case, `HasFormula` could be used, but it isn't needed because the code could work directly with .Value and only update the cells that are the target of the calculation. The only time a formula might be overwritten is if Cost's target cell already contains a formula, and in that case overwriting it is the desired behaviour.

Comment: @TomRobinson Thank you again, I wanted to tag your name in original because you helped me to discover this smooth way to do loops. I hope that this is the final step in my VBA practicing, but you never know.
Also thank you TheEngineer for participation.